# %load_ext rpy2.ipython Image not found error

Tags: rpy2

I am trying to use the magic command in ipython, something I saw here: 
[rpy2 slides](http://lgautier.github.io/jpd-pdapr-slides/)

I have done the following:

```
import rpy2.ipython
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

But I get the following error:

> ```
> ImportError: dlopen(/Users/XXX/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so,
> ```
>
> 2): Library not loaded: libicuuc.54.dylib
>         Referenced from: /Users/XXX/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so
>         Reason: image not found

Some relevant information:

- OS: MacOS Sierra
- Python: 2.7.12
- iPython: IPython 5.1.0
- rpy2: 2.8.3
- Did the `pip install singledispatch` but the error still persists
- r installed using conda
- Also have a copy of R from CRAN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because I installed R through conda, I also needed to install rpy2 through conda and not through pip. To install rpy2 through conda do the following,

```
conda install -c r rpy2
```

This worked really well. However, it is unclear why installing rpy2 through pip does not work.

Comment: installing rpy2 thru pip utilizes your local installation of R. If rpy2 doesn't find R in your path variable or doesn't like it it will throw an error. On the other hand conda's rpy2 installs an independent version or R. When you run the `conda install -c r rpy2` you'll notice the base R packages installing. As a result you'll need to install 
any additional packages you want to use into the rpy2 copy of R.
This is the main reason why the conda install is more stable.